# Bar chart in SAS using sum of two columns

Tags: graph, sas

I am using the Free University Edition of SAS. I would like to create a bar chart to compare the total of two columns. I created the columns in the code below from the dummy variable `RED_CAR`. I want to have the total of each of these columns as two separate bars in a bar chart. I am aware that I didn't need to make both columns as they are mutually exclusive but I thought it would be easier to plot.

```
data insurance;
set insurance;
Red_Crash =0;
Red_No_Crash=0;
if RED_CAR =1 & TARGET_FLAG =1 then do; Red_Crash =1; end;
if RED_CAR =1 & TARGET_FLAG =0 then do; Red_No_Crash=1;end;
run;
```

Comment: Posting what you've tried and what your graph might look like would help. And sample data would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that option is available on that edition of this SAS institute software.

I know that if you are using the Academy or the Express version of [WPS](https://www.worldprogramming.com/) you can solve your problem using the GCHART proceduce, if you slightly change your DATA step to:

```
DATA insurance;
    set insurance;
    if RED_CAR =1 & TARGET_FLAG =1 then do; Red_Crash =1; end;
    if RED_CAR =1 & TARGET_FLAG =0 then do; Red_Crash =0;end;
RUN;
```

Then is easy to plot using GCHART

```
PROC GCHART data = insurance;
    VBAR red_crash;
RUN;
```

Comment: GChart is not available in SAS UE, SGPLOT is available.